# How to apply filter on search parameter in DSL query

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a huge customer data saved in elastic search

My query is below

`{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "Mobile"}}}`

- Question 1

I need to filter out `{country: Germany}`

`"filter": [ { "term": { "Country.keyword": "Germany" }}]`

- Question 2

I need to filter out

`{country: Germany}`  and `{continent:Europe}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

```
{
  "item":"mobile are essential",
  "Country":"India",
  "continent":"Europe"
}
{
  "item":"mobile",
  "Country":"Germany",
  "continent":"Europe"
}
{
  "item":"mobile",
  "Country":"Germany",
  "continent":"asia"
}
```

For your 1st question, `need to filter out {country: Germany}`, you need to wrap your query in bool query:

```
{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Mobile"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Country.keyword": "Germany"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64278091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15965708,
        "_source": {
          "item": "mobile",
          "Country": "Germany",
          "continent": "Europe"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64278091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.15965708,
        "_source": {
          "item": "mobile",
          "Country": "Germany",
          "continent": "asia"
        }
      }
    ]
```

For your second question, try out this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Mobile"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Country.keyword": "Germany"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "continent": "Europe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64278091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.22920428,
        "_source": {
          "item": "mobile",
          "Country": "Germany",
          "continent": "Europe"
        }
      }
    ]
```